# Can I use JQuery to traverse/examine downloaded web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to augment a web page with additional information from another web page.  Is there a way to somehow do the following (very simplified, but I want to be able to "run jquery traversal" on the downloaded page)?  The web page being downloaded is in the same domain as the web page this script is running on, so there should not be a cross-site scripting issue.

```
$.ajax({url: theUrl,
        success: function(data)
        {
                var result =  $.loadandparsewebpage(data).find("span[id*='reviewerRepeater']").first().text();
                $("body").append("<div>" + result + "</div>");
        }
});
```

Comment: yes you can as long as you respect CORS - use `$.get`.

Comment: You can use [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments), using the "Loading page fragments" syntax to load it into the current document.